# Azure Function is not logging LogMetric telemetry to Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a 3-week-old Function on the v2 SDK and uses the out-box App Insights support, i.e. just set the environment variable and ...magic.

I did read that by default it doesn't send **Information** level logs to AppInsights and this looks correct because I can't see any of my information tracing but I do see occasional errors I've logged out with my custom message.

But for metrics, its broken. I can see some semblance of my telemetry in the logs, sort of. It's strange.

Look.

[image: VS Code screen shot]

---

Now look at these curious logs.

[image: Log Analytics screen shot of some log lines]

...see those `n/a` that match the `LogMetric` lines in my code?

---

And when I search explicitly for one of them, nothing is found.

[image: Log Analytics screen shot with no results]

---

And if I drill down on those `n/a` logs.

[image: Log Analytics screen shot of strange log entries with not much data]

...they're pretty empty.

---

Is it me or is this all rather fishy?

How do I log metrics from a Function in a way that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, for the metric, do you mean custom metrics? If yes, then you should find it in the `customMetrics` table in your app insights.

[image]

**Second**, what's the method are you using to send metrics? From your code, what's the implementation of `this.Logger?.LogMetric` method?

For sending metrics, you can use [TrackMetric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#examples-1)(just tested with this method, and works) or [GetMetric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#getmetric) method.

A sample code use TrackMetric(deprecated, but still can use) / GetMetric(recommended) method:

```
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key";
            TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();            
            client.TrackMetric("my metric", 60);
            client.GetMetric("my metric").TrackValue(89);
            client.Flush();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I tried `customMetrics` but no joy. The extension method I'm using was "just there" for me to use, it comes from the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` package. It's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-metrics-logging

I might post a GitHub question off that article as clearly it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay I switched to your code and its all good. I'll raise an issue about that extension method.

Comment: @LukePuplett, can you provide the link to the issue you opened? I'm unable to find it and today i still see this problem and would like to check

Comment: @FEST I think I left that company/gig and never filed it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the settings in the host.json file were excluding the metrics from getting to Application Insights. The metrics are being logged at the `Information` level and I originally had mine configured for the `Warning` level.

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "Function.<function name>": "Information", //<--won't see metrics if set to Warning
        ...
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2) for more information on configuring the logging levels.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful when want to make Default warning and change the function method to information